# How do I create a pointer to an array of object pointers

Tags: c++

I have a two-dimensional array of pointers to Block objects

```
Block* grid[GRID_COLUMNS][GRID_ROWS];
for (int i=0; i>GRID_COLUMNS; i++)
{
    for (int k=0; k>GRID_ROWS; k++)
    {
        grid[i][k] = NULL;
    }
}
```

How do I create a pointer to grid?

```
??? // create pointer to grid here

myBlock.ShiftDown(???); // pass pointer to grid to the function
```

The function definition of myBlock.ShiftDown. What should I put in place of the ??? to make this work?

```
void Block::ShiftDown(???)
{
    if (row == GRID_ROWS)
        ???grid[column][row] = this;
    else
        row++;
}
```

Edit: what I'm trying to do here is letting Block::ShiftDown manipulate grid. If there's an easier way to do this then I would like to hear about it.

Comment: Your `ShiftDown` function writes outside the array bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem with:

```
void Block::ShiftDown(Block* g[GRID_COLUMNS][GRID_ROWS])
{
    if (row == GRID_ROWS)
        g[column][row] = this;
    else
        row++;
}
```

and call it:

```
myBlock.ShiftDown(grid);
```

Comment: not that you do not pass an array here. `g` is a pointer, nothing more. `grid` _decays) into a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, as beginner I didn't realize it was this easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C/C++ the name of the array itself is a pointer to the first element of the array. So in your case *grid* is itself a pointer to the first column of the first row of your array

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a type-alias:

```
using my_array_type =
    std::array<std::array<std::shared_ptr<Block>, GRID_ROWS>, GRID_COLUMNS>;
```

Now you can use `my_array` to declare types:

```
my_array_type grid;
```

And of course use that type to declare function arguments:

```
void Block::ShiftDown(my_array_type& grid);
```

---

And if you don't have a C++11 compiler, and so don't have `std::array` and can't use `using` to create type aliases, then there's the old `typedef`:

```
typedef Block *my_array_type[GRID_COLUMNS][GRID_ROWS];
```